# What are the common ways to distinguish between identifier of local variables and global variables?

Tags: coding-style, rename, naming-conventions, naming, prefix

I write a function with using same identifier for local variable and globel variable, as shown as following codes:

```py
def func(time_len, num_nodes):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    time_len, num_nodes = input_arrs.shape
    func(time_len=time_len, num_nodes=num_nodes)
```

I want to reduce this kind of naming style to avoid ambiguity.
But the only method I can think of is adding prefix or suffix to identifier, like this:

```py
def func(time_len, num_nodes):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global_time_len, global_num_nodes = input_arrs.shape
    func(time_len=global_time_len, num_nodes=global_num_nodes)
```

My question is:
What are the common ways or conventions to distinguish between local variables and global variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not typical Python Style to do what you suggest. https://pep8.org/#global-variable-names

However, there are several other styles you can take inspiration from.

You can try a `g_` prefix to note a global variable. I've seen this used although it is not popular.

Some code styles also have guidance on global variable where you use `UpperCamelCase` for global variables (and functions) and `lowerCamelCase` for locals. If you instead prefer underscores, it's easily modified to be `Upper_With_Under` and `lower_with_under`.

Typically, in modern code styles we don't rely on naming to note which variable is in what scope. If a programmer cannot keep track of which name is in what scope, that should tell you that the file is too complex with too many names and too many overlapping scopes. You should take this confusion and turn it into a round of simplification, modularization, and abstraction so that the code is easier to understand and keep in your mind.

Code that is too complex for you to keep track of is code that is too complex to modify.

Answer (score 1):

The first observation is that if the variables are global you don't need to pass them to the function; it already has access to them. However, the best strategy is to avoid global variables if possible so the function is self-contained.

In general it's good practice to use more descriptive names for global variables, or at least avoid unnecessary abbreviations, for instance *elapsed_time* and *node_count*. I always let the last word describe the variable in its most basic sense; the first variable is a *time* and the second is a *count*. With this practice you can see at a glance what kind of value you are dealing with.

Remember that each variable or function parameter exists in a context; a global variable exist in the context of the module and a parameter and a local variable exist in the context of a function. That alone often implies what the name should be.

Encoding the global property in the variable name is an ugly solution if you ask me. It is ugly because a variable should be named after what kind of values it holds, nothing more and nothing less.